# OPENJSON with Array of Arrays

Tags: sql-server

I have a large JSON structure (array of arrays) consisting of string values (e.g. "1") that identify each section.

How would I utilize OPENJSON to parse all the information correctly?

A subset of the JSON data:

```
{"products":[
    {"1":[
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16326","location":"06","quantity":"71"},
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16327","location":"06","quantity":"44"},
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16328","location":"06","quantity":"47"}
        ]
    }
]}
```

I've tried numerous variations of the following without any success:

```
SELECT @json1 = BulkColumn
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\4\test3.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j

 SELECT product, category, item FROM OPENJSON (@json1, '$.products[0]')
  With (
    product varchar(20),
    category varchar(20),
    item varchar(20)
  )
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the result set you're after here exactly?

Comment: Is there always just one section? What should happen if there's more than one? Are you going to do anything with the section number? Your code is trivially fixed by using `$.products[0]."1"` instead of `$.products[0]`, but this assumes you only want section 1.

Comment: I have hundreds of sections all formatted the same way. The result set that I get back is just a NULL value. I've tried using AS JSON and saw no difference.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen Mostert - it works! I feel like a fool for not trying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the expected result, but you might try something along these lines:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{"products":[
    {"1":[
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16326","location":"06","quantity":"71"},
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16327","location":"06","quantity":"44"},
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16328","location":"06","quantity":"47"}
        ]
    }
]}';

SELECT B.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json,N'$.products')
WITH([1] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.[1])
WITH(product NVARCHAR(100)
    ,category INT
    ,item INT
    ,[location] INT
    ,quantity INT) B;
```

In cases with multiple sections, where you need the "1" as a column in your result set, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{"products":[
    {"1":[
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16326","location":"06","quantity":"71"},
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16327","location":"06","quantity":"44"},
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16328","location":"06","quantity":"47"}
        ]
    }
    ,{"2":[
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16326","location":"06","quantity":"71"},
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16327","location":"06","quantity":"44"},
        {"product":"01-223","category":"32","item":"16328","location":"06","quantity":"47"}
        ]
    }
]}';

SELECT B.[key] AS NumericObjectName
      ,C.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json,N'$.products') A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.[value]) B
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(B.[value])
WITH(product NVARCHAR(100)
    ,category INT
    ,item INT
    ,[location] INT
    ,quantity INT) C
```

Comment: Thank you Shnugo - nice answer. I tried many times to get CROSS APPLY to work with my queries and could see what I did wrong. thanks for explaining.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have been trying to achieve with my result set.